# Does Azure Synapse managed private endpoint support Azure Cosmos Db for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse, azure-private-link

I created a Synapse with the "Managed virtual network" enabled, my Synapse need to access a "private" Aure cosmos db for PostgreSQL.

I tried to add "managed private endpoint (Azure Database for PostgreSQL)" in Synapse to my Cosmos for PostgreSQL, when adding the endpoint we have two choices for target sub-resource : "Coordinator" and "postgresqlServer". i created the managed private endpoint of target sub-resource "coordinator", then manually approve it, but creating a linked service to db in Synapse fails, for the second target sub-resource "postgresqlServer" the creation of managed private endpoint is not possible ("provision state" = failed).

is Azure cosmos Db for PostgreSQL supported in Synapse Managed virtual network scenario ?